# AWS S3 nodejs - How to get object by his prefix

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm searching how check if an object exist in my aws s3 bucket in nodejs without list all my object (~1500) and check the prefix of the object but I cannot find how.

The format is like that:

```
<prefix I want to search>.<random string>/
```

Ex:

```
tutturuuu.dhbsfd7z63hd7833u/
```

Comment: If you know the key (aka name) of the object, you can use [headObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) call in node js..

Comment: I need to check if the prefix of object exist like that "<name I want to check>.<other data>" and not all the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't know the entire object Key, you will need to perform a list and filter by prefix. The AWS nodejs sdk [provides such a method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property). Here is an example:

```
s3.listObjectsV2({
  Bucket: 'youBucket',
  MaxKeys: 1,
  Prefix: 'tutturuuu.'
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  const objectExists = data.Contents.length > 0
  console.log(objectExists);
});
```

Note that it is important to use `MaxKeys` in order to reduce network usage. If more than one object has the prefix, then you will need to return everything and decide which one you need.

This API call will return metadata only. After you have the full key you can use `getObject` to retrieve the object contents.